# Problema en la carga de un archivo Python

Tags: python, rutas

Soy nuevo en Python, estoy usando un script desarrollado por otra persona y tengo problemas para cargar un archivo *txt*, adjunto el código donde muestro el nombre del archivo y la ruta donde se encuentra ese archivo.
He probado de dos formas que es lo que he encontrado en algunas otras respuestas a preguntas antiguas.

Muestro también el error que me notifica y las líneas donde sucede.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

---

Código de definición de archivo y ruta:

```
nombre_archivo_txt = "20201203_135914_FPT_Finales_corr"
dir_abs = r"C:\Users\ezxt99251\Desktop\Logs_a_Py"
```

También he probado de esta forma:

```
nombre_archivo_txt = "20201203_135914_FPT_Finales_corr"
dir_abs = "C:\\Users\\ezxt99251\\Desktop\\Logs_a_Py"
```

Error que reporta:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 616, in open
    raise IOError ("%s not found." %path)

OS error: C:Users\ezxt99251\Desktop\Logs_a_Py20201203_135914_FPT_Finales_corr not found.
```

Answer (score 2):

El error indica que el archivo que intentas abrir no existe, esto puede verificarse en dos casos: el archivo no existe o el nombre de archivo y/o directorio especificado son incorrectos.

**En esta respuesta daré por sentado que has verificado la existencia del archivo que intentas abrir.**

### Como declarar correctamente el directorio del archivo

Te recomiendo utilizar `os.path` para especificar el directorio del archivo y evitar tener problemas con los slash `\` `/`. Ejemplo:

```
import os

directorio = os.path('C:','Users','ezxt99251','Desktop','Logs_a_Py')
```

### El nombre del archivo

Hablas de un archivo de extensión *txt*, pero no veo que hayas especificado la extensión en el nombre del archivo, este debería ser:

```
nombre_archivo_txt = "20201203_135914_FPT_Finales_corr.txt"
```

> Consejo: Si estás usando Windows y te estás encaminando en la programación deberías desactivar la opción del sistema operativo de ocultar las extensiones de los archivos.

### Como leer un archivo en Python

En conclusión puedes abrir un archivo en Python de la siguiente manera:

```
import os

nombre_archivo_txt = "20201203_135914_FPT_Finales_corr.txt"
directorio = os.path('C:', 'Users', 'ezxt99251', 'Desktop', 'Logs_a_Py')

# Une el directorio al nombre del archivo
archivo = os.path(directorio, nombre_archivo_txt)

with open(archivo, 'r') as f:
    # La variable datos contiene los datos del archivo
    datos = f.read()
```